# MySQL remove left over time from datetime converted to varchar. Substr()?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, substr

I'm doing things a bit backwards:

So I have converted a column from datetime into varchar (there are valid reasons). My issue is all of the 0's from TIME have also varied over. Trying to use concat() to strip the string.

> Ex: 2013-12-12 00:00:00
>
> Output: 2013-12-12

The issue is, not ALL the varchars have the "00:00:00" ending. Some of them were put in AFTER the system went over to varchar instead of datetime So i can just strip say -X from the string without first checking if it is larger then say 12 chars.

I was thinking something like

```
UPDATE logic_intern_report_link SET comp_date=SUBSTR(comp_date,0,10)
```

However this ends up removing all values for that column.

Comment: Just curious. What are those reasons? Maybe we have another solution than converting to varchar.

Comment: ... Wait, you're _storing_ them as varchar?  There's **NO** good reason to store a date value as a character value - you're just begging to get invalid data in that column, and you're going to have to convert it to date to do certain types of comparisons (although at least you have a SARGable format).

Comment: The field is longer being used for comparison and the client wants to put things in as say "next Tuesday". It is no longer a true date field...more of a "comments" field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE  logic_intern_report_link 
SET     comp_date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE(comp_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: My Hero, it wont let me accept the answer for another 10 minutes but that did EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

I agree with JW.'s solution, but just to answer your question:
the reason you're getting empty values with your original query is that the SUBSTR() function requires a 1-based starting index, not the zero you provided as the second parameter.
Try this

```
SELECT SUBSTR(comp_date,1,10) FROM logic_intern_report_link
```

to see the difference.

(For full disclosure: the SUBSTR() function would also accept a negative starting index)

Comment: Thanks, first person to answer why my original snippet didn't work. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
update logic_intern_report_link 
set comp_date = REPLACE(comp_date, ' 00:00:00', '')
```